# How to use for loop to find a prime number?

Tags: for-loop, user-defined-functions

**def check_prime(x):
for i in range(2,x):
if x%i==0:
return False
else: return True**

Why is this code not working properly. This code returns true even for some non prime numbers. eg:- 9 , 25 ,...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To make your question helpful for other askers, and to make it easier to those who want to answer, please make sure your question is formatted properly. You should post your code as code, not as bold text. How to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `True` right away when you find one number that doesn't divide `x`, which is wrong. You're supposed to return `True` when all number greater or equal to 2 and less than `x` doesn't divide `x`. To fix this, remove the `else` code, and return `True` after the `for` loop is over.

Here's the full code:

```
def check_prime(x):
    for i in range(2, x):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```